# How to solve gradle error in flutter with android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I Installed android studio with all requirements for flutter, when I run flutter doctor everything is fine and installed correctly. I created a normal android project and it's running fine with no errors. Now after I created new flutter project I get this error whenever I run the project. 
I couldn't solve it.

> Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
>   Initializing gradle...
>   Finished with error: ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\Nesma\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\flutter_apptest\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
>   Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 503 Too many open connections"
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling(HttpURLConnection.java:2142)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:183)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect0(HttpURLConnection.java:2729)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect(HttpURLConnection.java:2641)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1824)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
  Command: C:\Users\Nesma\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\flutter_apptest\android\gradlew.bat -v
```

Comment: seems like there is a problem with network connection.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you don't have the `gradle-4.10.2-all` version and when you run it is trying to download it without success.

If you already created another project with gradle, you can check the versions you have in: `C:\Users\{USERNAME}\.gradle\wrapper\dists\` and modify the gradle configuration of your new project.

Comment: I downloaded the required gradle version manually and unzipped it in the path you mentioned but still get the same error

Comment: Copy to `.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.10.2-all/9fahxiiecdb76a5g3aw9oi8rv/` use the same path for this version of gradle :)

Comment: I already copied it to that directory. but still having the same error. How can I make the project identify this version which I downloaded and copied ?

Comment: Modify the file `yourproject/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` according to your gradle version. The line `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.x.x-all.zip`

Comment: sorry. I'm still having the same issue. That did not solve the issue

Comment: you can modify your question including that you downloaded manually and you can also add screenshot to better understand your problem, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by doing two things:

- downgrading (but maybe you have to upgrade) value for `gradle`. Go to `android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties` and change value for `distributionUrl`. In my case - from `5.6.2` to `5.4.1`
- setting up proxy settings (because I have corporate firewall). Go to `android\gradle.properties` and add something like this. If you need to add user, google it

```
    systemProp.http.proxyHost=somehost
    systemProp.http.proxyPort=port
    systemProp.https.proxyHost=somehost
    systemProp.https.proxyPort=port
```